# Android Installing kernel with custom config

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I want to install a different kernel on my Samsung i9300 (some config flags enabled)

So far I have installed the custom ROM

```
Slim-4.4.2.build.3-OFFICIAL-3091
```

It uses the following kernel version so far:

```
$ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.0.80+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Feb 15 15:10:26 CET 2014 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

The kernel version of my [source](https://github.com/SlimRoms/kernel%5fsamsung%5fsmdk4412) from which I create my kernel.zip has a newer version:

```
.../kernel_samsung_smdk4412$ gedit Makefile 
VERSION = 3
PATCHLEVEL = 0
SUBLEVEL = 80
EXTRAVERSION =
NAME = Sneaky Weasel
...
```

I used the following toolchain to build the kernel successfully:

1)

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7
```

2)

```
sudo gedit .bashrc

export PATH=${PATH}:~/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin
```

3)

```
cd /kernel_samsung_smdk4412/

make clean -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi-

make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi- slim_i9300_defconfig

make -j4 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi-
```

I use [this guide](http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/getting-started-building-a-kernel-from-source) to create the flashable zip file.
It uses koush's AnyKernel to install the new Kernel with TWRP 2.6.3.1

The [updater-script](https://github.com/koush/AnyKernel/blob/master/META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script) looks like that so far:

```
ui_print("AnyKernel Updater by Koush.");
ui_print("Extracting System Files...");
set_progress(1.000000);
mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/mmcblk0p9", "/system");
package_extract_dir("system", "/system");
unmount("/system");
ui_print("Extracting Kernel files...");
package_extract_dir("kernel", "/tmp");
ui_print("Installing kernel...");
set_perm(0, 0, 0777, "/tmp/dump_image");
set_perm(0, 0, 0777, "/tmp/mkbootimg.sh");
set_perm(0, 0, 0777, "/tmp/mkbootimg");
set_perm(0, 0, 0777, "/tmp/unpackbootimg");
run_program("/tmp/dump_image", "boot", "/tmp/boot.img");
run_program("/tmp/unpackbootimg", "/tmp/boot.img", "/tmp/");
run_program("/tmp/mkbootimg.sh");
write_raw_image("/tmp/newboot.img", "boot");
ui_print("Done!");
```

The 4th line was edited because of what I have found [here](https://github.com/AOKP-i9100/buildscripts/blob/master/samsung/i9300/kernel%5fupdater-script#L11) for the i9300 .

When I flash the zip via TWRP everything seems fine but when rebooting the system the old kernel version and installation date is shown in the "About Phone" section of the Settings.

What did I miss?

Comment: Probably you did not overwrite the kernel.  If you want to be sure you can view /proc/version which is a direct kernel interface and so should be definitive.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Of course I did not overwrite the kernel, that is my problem! But I can't figure out why I didn't. The installation via TWRP did not fail so it seems that the installation worked. Therefore I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using AnyKernel to flash the zImage, I created a boot.img out of the zImage using [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=44670032&postcount=12) and then flashed it via [heimdall](http://glassechidna.com.au/heimdall/) on my i9300:

```
user@ubuntu1210:~/bootimg_tools$ perl split_bootimg.pl boot.img


user@ubuntu1210:~/bootimg_tools$ perl unpack_ramdisk boot.img-ramdisk.gz ramdisk


user@ubuntu1210:~/bootimg_tools$ perl repack_ramdisk ramdisk boot.img-ramdisk.cpio.gz


user@ubuntu1210:~/bootimg_tools$ cp /home/user/kernel_samsung_smdk4412/arch/arm/boot/zImage boot.img-kernel


user@ubuntu1210:~/bootimg_tools$ ./mkbootimg --kernel boot.img-kernel --ramdisk boot.img-ramdisk.cpio.gz --cmdline 'console=null androidboot.hardware=qcom user_debug=31 zcache' --base 0x80200000 --pagesize 2048 -o boot.img


user@ubuntu1210:~/bootimg_tools$ adb reboot bootloader

user@ubuntu1210:~/bootimg_tools$ sudo heimdall flash --BOOT boot.img --verbose
```